# Inconsistent Behaviour while executing a Background Task in Flask Web App

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, background-task

I am creating a flask web app which has a background task of making an API Calls every x seconds.The interval is decided based on a value coming from the API,if the value is True then and if the database don't have any data for counter it will insert a counter value 1.If it has a counter value it will increment the counter and update it on the database and the next call for this task will be after 40 seconds but if it is false the the next call will be in 10 seconds.Here is my code

```
import time
import threading


def writemotiondata():

    processing = False
    while True:
            deviceid = 'eb4f7839b63063bdec3ikc'
            openapi = authorization()
            openapi.connect()
            response = openapi.get("/v1.0/devices/{}".format(deviceid))
          
            result = response['result']
            status = result['status']
            value = status[0]['value']


            print(value)
            if (value == True):
                tempdata = motiondata.find()
                previousdata = [{item: key[item] for item in key if item != '_id'} for key in tempdata]

                if len(previousdata) == 0:

                    data = {"sensorname": "pir",
                            "numberofpeople": 1}
                    motiondata.insert_one(data).inserted_id
                   
                else:
                    count = previousdata[0]['numberofpeople']
                    count += 1
                    filter = {"sensorname": "pir"}
                    updateddata = {"$set": {"numberofpeople": count}}
                    motiondata.update_one(filter, updateddata)

                time.sleep(40)
              

            else:
                
                time.sleep(10)
               



if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=writemotiondata)
    t1.start()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here the expected output is if the value is True the task should increment the counter and update the database.For example if the previous count was 1,after completing the task the new count should be 2 and the task should be called to execute again in 40 seconds. If the value is false the task will be called again in 10 seconds.

However The output I am getting is the counter in my database gets incremented inconsistently,sometimes it gets incremented by 1 ,sometimes it gets incremented by 2 or 3.I have printed out the value and saw in 40 seconds sometimes the value true is being printed 2/3 times instead of one,same goes for false.Basically the task is being executed more than once,in that time interval.Can anyone please help me figure out why is this happening and what I am doing wrong.
**I am using a single thread,no more threads has been used in the code.**

Comment: Are you running your flask app under uvicorn or something with multiple worker processes?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes I am running it with gunicorn

Comment: Maybe try `gunicorn --workers=1` to initially test if that is the issue and makes your app work consistently before trying to find a solution.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes it seems to be working consistently now as I have changed the workers number to 1,thanks for helping me out,but I have an additional question,how to handle this for multiple workers

Comment: I don't really have enough details about what you are really trying to do, or why you need multiple workers, how many clients there are, how many devices there are to monitor or anything really to be able to help much. I suspect you need a single process, external to flask and gunicorn that manages everything and the flask API should maybe just signal or message that one controller to do stuff, but I'm only guessing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell There can 5/6 clients using the app at the same time,and the number of devices can be more than 100,the issue is after chaning the worker number to 1 in gunicorn If I have already opened the app in a client,and try to open it another client the second one seems to crash and wont load the data,Also the client is short polling the backend apis ,sending request in short intervals ,for example ,for a single device the client is sending 2 request in 30 seconds.